# How to test spring boot rest controller with Junit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I'm having an extremely hard time finding consistent resources on how to actually code Junit5 tests for Sprint Boot. Right now, I have have a very simple controller and my attempt at a Junit5 test, but I'm not even able to get the result back from a simple rest call. It's suppose to return an array of string values. I believe the main problem is the MockHttpServletResponse Header isn't appending a port on there, but I'd like it to be dynamically added so whoever pulls down the code can Junit5 test it just fine.

```
@RestController
public class CnlLetterController {

    
    @Autowired
    private CnlLetterService cnlLetterService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    private ServiceLetterService serviceLetterService;
    
    @GetMapping("/rest/cnl/templates")
    public List<String> findTemplates () {
        
        return cnlLetterService.getTemplates();
    }

    /* Other methods that don't matter right now */
}
```

TestController

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(CnlLetterController.class)
class CnlLetterControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private ClientRegistrationRepository crr;
    
    @MockBean
    private CnlLetterService cnlLetterService;
    
    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;
    
    @MockBean
    private ServiceLetterService serviceLetterService;
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testFindTemplates() throws Exception {
        
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/pis/rest/cnl/templates")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
        
    }
}
```

Junit console output

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /pis/rest/cnl/templates
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Accept:"application/json"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Location:"https://localhost/pis/rest/cnl/templates"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = https://localhost/pis/rest/cnl/templates
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /pis/rest/cnl/templates
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Accept:"application/json"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Location:"https://localhost/pis/rest/cnl/templates"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = https://localhost/pis/rest/cnl/templates
          Cookies = []
2020-07-20 13:37:29.648  INFO 12868 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Comment: First of all why do you have `/pis` at the beginning of the URL. Controller is not configured to handle it. I've took your code and changed only 1. url to /rest/cnl/template 2. removed all injected services and returned hardcoded list 3. removed dev profile. and it works. I guess there's some spring web configuration that is important but you haven't included.

Comment: It was mainly to test the url because it wasn't working for me.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I'm wondering why it's not including the port in my url. This may have to do with why it's not working for me.

Comment: Port is not needed as there is no actual http call executed. `MockMvc` emulates the call to servlet directly bypassing HTTP completely. There is no actual server running when the test is executed.

Comment: Alright, so that getTemplates() call goes to the service and then the service calls the repo -> database where the string of templates are stored. Would I have to Mock up that repo somehow and put data in it? Then attempt to get the call again to see if it worked?

Comment: Hmm. You are asking in comment something completely different. First of all it is a bad practice and also to answer this new question it is better to create a new question as some more information is needed before I (or someone else) can answer.

Comment: Okay. definitely noted and will do. May I ask where you put your hard coded list though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218241/discussion-between-roman-konoval-and-maze).